# Angularjs ngInit with filter override values

Tags: angularjs

I trying to init a filtered value without success. I'll use partial/ng-include so variable's name can't change.

I using angularjs v1.0.2 and I tried also with v1.1.1

```
<script>
    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.trains = [ 1, 2];
    }
</script>


<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-init="t = (trains | filter:1)">    
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:1 }}
  </div>
  <div ng-init="t = (trains | filter:2)">
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:2 }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The output

```
[2] [1]
[2] [2]
```

Here is this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/9q5D4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want...
But you can use directive in order to combine between ng-init and ng-include:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">    
    <my-directive field-name=1 train=2></my-directive>
    <my-directive field-name=2 train=17></my-directive>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.trains = [1, 2]; 
}

angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: 'isolate',
        template: "<div>{{exposeAttribute}} {{anotherOne}}</div>",
        controller: Ctrl,
        //templateUrl: "mytemplate.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.exposeAttribute = attr.fieldName;
            scope.anotherOne = attr.train;
        }
    };
});
```

and the output is:

1 2

2 17

http://jsfiddle.net/9q5D4/5/

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the `ng-init` expression (especially if you are initializing new variables). In your example you are running 2 separate expressions: `t = trains` and `filter:<X>`.

You should use `t = (trains | filter:<X>)`:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-init="t = (trains | filter:1)">    
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:1 }}
  </div>
  <div ng-init="tt = (trains | filter:2)">
    {{ tt }}
    {{ trains | filter:2 }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9q5D4/2/

Comment: The is almost what I want. I'll also use ng-include so I can't rename the variable.

Comment: @Damax what do you mean by "If I use partial"? Can you provide an example (fiddle)? Also, don't update your question with an answer, it will confuse further visitors...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to iterate through $scope.trains?  In that case you should use ng-repeat. I don't believe filters are applicable for ng-init.

http://jsfiddle.net/gtmuh/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="t in trains | filter:1">
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:1 }}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="t in trains | filter:2">
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:2 }}
  </div>
```

Comment: I want to keep the code DRY by using partial with ng-include. Inside the partial I iterate on t.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked out exactly why or how,
but seems like placing a ng-if attribute 
before the ng-init makes it work.

tested on angular 1.2+;

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-init="t = (trains | filter:1)">    
        {{ t }}
        {{ trains | filter:1 }}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="true" ng-init="t = (trains | filter:2)">
    {{ t }}
    {{ trains | filter:2 }}
    </div>
</div>
```