# Angular 1.3 ng-model-options passing parameter to onUpdate

Tags: angularjs

In angular 1.3, i see we have updateOn : blur etc..

```
<input 
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur'}">
```

Question: Can we pass in our own function `newFunctionCall` with parameters : blur ?? Something like ...

```
<input 
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ newFunctionCall('abc',123,search): 'default blur'}">
```

So that i can use two different input with different argument with the SAME model . LIKE

```
<input name="contains"
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ newFunctionCall('pqr',456,search): 'default blur'}">

<input name="startsWith"
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ newFunctionCall('abc',123,search): 'default blur'}">
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect your app to do

Comment: What is newFunctionCall supposed to do? I think you might be looking for ng-init with a custom filter like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238323/angularjs-nginit-with-filter-override-values) - but I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to uses two <input with different argument with the SAME model

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-` attributes to pass arguments into the scope:

```
<input 
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur'}"
  data-foo="456" data-bar="pqr">

<input 
  type="search" 
  ng-model="searchQuery" 
  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur'}"
  data-foo="123" data-bar="abc">
```

Use `angular.element` to get the values:

```
  angular.element(this).attr("data-foo")
```

**References**

- [AngularJS's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)
- [How to get an element's attribute with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105185/how-to-get-an-elements-attribute-with-angularjs)